# Previous page in Android Studio Webview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

Currently I'm actually making a mobile app for my website (wordpress) using `Webview` in Android Studio.
But while navigating into the different pages of it, when I want to go to the previous page using the back button of my android device, my app just close. 
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(webView.canGoBack()){
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: in your activity.

Comment: Thank you that's what i needed!

Answer (score 0):

To implement `Back Navigation` for `WebViews`, As from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html), you can override `onBackPressed()` and and proxy to the `WebView` if it has history state as:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
      mWebView.goBack();
      return;
  }

  // Otherwise defer to system default behavior.
  super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Or, you can check the event was `Back` button and if there's history, then you can also use:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history

    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, show default behavior
    // system behavior (probably exit the activity)

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Thank's that's help me a lot!